# How to check sub class type in super class in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to get sub class type in super class.
I tried

```
if(this is SubClass1)
```

in the super class
but failed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There might be a better way than checking the type of the base class.

Comment: If using the "is" keyword didn't work then you coded something wrong.

Comment: I think this actually will fail because "this" is "upcast" to the super class type in the code that's defined in the super type (I'm not entirely sure about this as it's not documented but I've run into similar behavior, I wonder if creating a new instance of that class in the super class would result in the same issue, u need to be careful if you try this that you're not creating an infinite recursion/loop).

Comment: Sorry,There is a mistake in my codes. This method worked. Using override is a better way,I'm maintaining the lagecy program and cannot use the override way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works :

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestSuperClass extends Sprite{
        public function TestSuperClass(){
            super();
            trace((new SuperClass).isSubclass); // Output : false
            trace((new Extended).isSubclass); // Output : true
        }
    }
}

internal class SuperClass
{
    public function get isSubclass() : Boolean{
        return this is Extended;
    }
}

internal class Extended extends SuperClass {}
```

You can do it dynamically (that's ugly, not performance friendly, but it does the job) :

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestSuperClass extends Sprite{
        public function TestSuperClass(){
            super();

            trace((new SuperClass).isSubclass); // Output : false
            trace((new SuperClass).superClass); // Output : Object
            trace((new Extended).isSubclass); // Output : true
            trace((new Extended).superClass); // Output : SuperClass
        }
    }
}
import flash.utils.describeType;

internal class SuperClass
{
    public function get isSubclass() : Boolean{
        return describeType(this).@base.toString() != "Object";
    }

    public function get superClass() : String
    {
        return describeType(this).@base.toString().split("::").pop();
    }
}

internal class Extended extends SuperClass {}
```

Comment: You're right, I added a way to do it dynamically. I'm agree with the fact that's not nice but you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

The super class doesn't know about  his sub classes and shouldn't know. A subclass extends his superclass so should and knows about his super class.

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. There should be an other (better) way to solve for your problem/architecture.

Comment: The super class can know about his sub classes

Comment: @Simsoft I disagree, what I mean to say is what is being asked by the OP should be possible however it is not a good practice to write a base class that depends on knowledge of it's sub-classes as you immediately have ruined the ability to just arbitrarily extend from that object now without going in and modifying it's code (not absolutely necessarily true, but it creates this possibility).

Comment: That's to say sure it's possible, but if someone doesn't understand the implications I wouldn't really suggest it.

Comment: I agree, It can be usefull sometime but you need to be carefull

Comment: This way works. I know it's not a good idea,I have some restricts so I have to use this way.